# Как изменить в Arduino значение delay через переменную int

Tags: arduino

Нужно изменить частоту мигания светодиодом на число которое будет слаться через bluetooth с андроид смартфона на плату ардуино. Даное число должно работать беспрерывно в loop() а у меня получается только изменение частоты на одну секунду а дальше опять ничего. Вот код который есть:

```
int  LED = 12;// LED pin
int val;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // initialization
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  //Serial.println("Press 1 to LED ON or 0 to LED OFF...");
}
void loop() {

if(Serial.available()>0)
{
  val = Serial.read();
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(val);                       // wait for a val
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(val); 
}
}
```

Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В алгоритме есть ошибка. На каждой итерации функции loop() используется функция delay(), во время исполнения которой микроконтроллер занят только этим.

Поэтому данный алгоритм будет корректно обрабатывать данные, полученные по последовательному порту, только если время задержки будет составлять меньше половины времени, требуемого для передачи одного символа.

При приёме символы поступают в буфер, из которого их нужно прочитать. Поэтому следует изменить алгоритм следующим образом:

```
void loop()
{
   while( Serial.available() > 0 )
      val = Serial.read();
   digitalWrite( LED, HIGH );
   delay( val );
   digitalWrite( LED, LOW );
   delay( val );
}
```

При  этом в качестве значения задержки будет использоваться последнее принятое значение.

Однако при этом микроконтроллер не сможет изменить частоту мигания, пока алгоритм не отработает очередную итерацию мигания. Можно изменить алгоритм таким образом, чтобы микроконтроллер реагировал на полученные данные более активно.

```
int val = 255;
int lastTime = 0;
int state = OFF;

void loop()
{
   if ( millis() - lastTime > val ) {
      if ( state == OFF )
         digitalWrite( LED, ON );
      else
         digitalWrite( LED, OFF );
      lastTime = millis();
   }
   while ( Serial.available() > 0 )
      val = Serial.read();
}
```

Данный алгоритм не использует функцию delay(). Вместо этого на каждой итерации цикла проверяется, сколько прошло миллисекунд с момента, когда светодиод был включен или выключен.